# Why does my pip access two site-packages?

Tags: python, windows, pip, path, pythonpath

I have a bit of confusion with `pip` and multiple `python` installations.
When running `python -m pip install pb_tool` I get console output:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pb_tool in c:\osgeo4w\apps\python39\lib\site-packages (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\hbh1\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pb_tool) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: Sphinx in c:\users\hbh1\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pb_tool) (6.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Click in c:\osgeo4w\apps\python39\lib\site-packages (from pb_tool) (7.1.2)
...
```

**I am wondering, why there are mixed site-packages paths, some in `c:\osgeo4w\apps\` and some in `c:\users\hbh1\appdata\...`?**

I installed pb_tool with the OSGeo4W python, I'd expect to find it and its requirements found/installed in `c:\osgeo4w\...`, not (even partially?!) in the `c:\users\hbh1\appdata\...`, especially when running `pip` with `python -m`.

To elaborate: This is not necessarily a problem, but I'd like to understand, why and also if/how I can circumvent this behavior. It caused me some confusion as to which python installation has which modules installed, and I'd like to keep things separate and an overview over where I installed what.

Some time back I ran `pip install pb_tool` in my dev shell and couldn't run `pb_tool` afterwards, despite the successful install. I assume, the problem is, that I didn't have `c:\users\hbh1\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages` on the PATH in that current environment. But somehow `pip` knew it, installed `pb_tool` there and `python` didn't know about it (I didn't add it, since I'd like a "clean and separated" dev enviroment with it's own python packages)...
I carefully checked PATH, my python/pip versions and which is which (cleaning PATH, using `where pip`/`where python` and `py -0b` to check the windows python launcher as well). My setup basically is:

```
  # add to PATH depending on the version I use
  C:\Apps\Python39\
  C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39  # respectively C:\OSGeo4W\bin

  # and their corresponding script dirs
  C:\Apps\Python39\Scripts
  C:\Users\hbh1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts
  C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts

  # and if relevant: Windows Python Launcher listing these (py -0p), where I only use the first (the second one is not on PATH):
  -3.9-64        C:\Apps\Python39\python.exe *
  -2.7-32        C:\Apps\ArcGIS\Python27\ArcGIS10.8\python.exe
```

C:\OSGeo4W\ is a dev environment for me and I use a "clean" shell for command line tools I use with it (meaning that I don't use the system PATH, but start with a .bat in which I clean the PATH and only add what I specifically need, plus a few general sytem paths).

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
set path=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%WINDIR%\system32;%WINDIR%;%WINDIR%\system32\WBem
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39\Scripts
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\lib
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\bin

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39

set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%PATH%

cmd.exe
```

I am still puzzled, why in this environment, `pip install` would put anything in the `c:\users\hbh1\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages` which is "normally" used by my `C:\Apps\Python39\` installation.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the content of the `pyvenv.cfg` file in the virtual environment? In particular I would like to see if the "system site packages" feature is enabled or not.

Comment: I'd gladly do, but not sure where to find that. But to clarify, neither is a *virtual* environment (in the python venv module sense), but both are actual standalone python installations. I assume there is a difference.

Comment: Oh... no virtual environment? Okay, I had not understood that. -- Well I am not sure then. -- Typically I would say that there is something happening either with the `sys.path` Python variable, or with the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Maybe you can try to run `python -m site` with each of your Python interpreters and try to figure things out from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting [`PYTHONNOUSERSITE`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONNOUSERSITE) so that Python won't add the user site-packages directory to `sys.path`. This can be made permanent in OSGeo4W by adding this line to `python3.bat`:

```
SET PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1
```

the location of this configuration file may depend on how OSGeo4W was installed, mine is in `C:\OSGeo4W\etc\ini\`